# While running a performance test using Blaze Meter with JMeter script. Load graph is showing inaccurate data

Tags: jmeter, performance, performance-testing, test-report, blazemeter

While executing JMeter scripts with ultimate thread group, the graphs are showing the wrong wrong ramp up. I have checked the JMeter logs and they are perfectly showing the start and end time of each thread. However, the Blaze Meter logs show differently which leads to incorrect rampup in graphs.

- Total user count : 20,
- Ultimate thread group : 3,
- Ultimate thread group 1 : 10 users with 30 sec startup time,
- Ultimate thread group 1 : 5 users with 15 sec startup time and delay is 30 sec,
- Ultimate thread group 3 : 5 users with 15 sec startup time and delay is 45 sec

Answer (score 1):

This question should rather go to [BlazeMeter Support](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket).

In order to get comprehensive help here we'll need to reproduce your issue and for this we'll need to see your [.jmx Test Plan](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan), the full one, you can replace your real Samplers with i.e. [Dummy Samplers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-dummy-sampler)

Or at least you need to clarify what is the value of the `Run Thread Groups consecutively" box on the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level

[image]